# How to be sure that autoplay script for HTML video on Chrome will work?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I want to make the video on HTML autoplays, given that Chrome prevents autoplay attr in HTML to play the video.

Here's my code :

```html
<video id="video" width="400">
  <source src="chess.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("video");
vid.autoplay = true;
vid.load();
```

The behavior is weird. First, I'm working on Eclipse and everything works perfectly fine on the eclipse browser.

When it comes to Chrome, the video sometimes works, sometimes need a clear-cache refresh to work... Not working with the first time opening the link. And now it's not working at all...

Any help?

Comment: instead of javascript you can use autoplay attribute `<video id="video" autoplay width="400"  >`

Comment: autoplay doesn't work with chrome because of some regulations...

Answer (score 2):

You need to refer to [Chrome Autoplay Policy Changes](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) before you try any scripts.

Chrome's autoplay policies are simple:

- Muted autoplay is always allowed.
- Autoplay with sound is allowed if:

  - User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).
  - On desktop, the user's Media Engagement    Index threshold has been
    crossed, meaning the user has previously    play video with sound.
  - On  mobile, the user has [added the site to    their home screen].
- Top frames can delegate autoplay permission to    their iframes to
  allow autoplay with sound

Comment: yes i read the policy ...what i understand is there's a regulation on html autoplay attribute... but i'm wondering if there's a workaround script that plays the video and already my 3-line script played it.. but sometimes it doesn't play in the first time and it plays with a refresh ... and sometimes it doesn't play at all .. i don't understand.

Comment: Yes i know, i have faced this myself .only workaround is to start the video as muted and then give the option to the user to unmute the video